# Interning of non String (non int/long) objects in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, string-interning

I was going through this documentation from Oracle :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html

And came across this piece of code regarding type annotation

Class instance creation expression:

```
new @Interned MyObject();
```

Does it mean Java8 or future versions is-allowing/will-allow interning of non String/long/int objects ?

Comment: If that is meant to be [`com.sun.istack.internal.Interned`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/istack/internal/Interned.java?av=f), then no. It's meant only for `String`s, but the language doesn't enforce that. The annotation processors will.

Comment: Note, that documentation of `com.sun.istack.internal.Interned` clearly speaks about Strings only. It is more likely that Checker Framework annotation is what article authors had in mind (especially, granted, that they mention it in the linked [article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there are no such plans. It's just an example how annotations can be used. I guess it can be implemented by third-party annotation processors like [project Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html), but unlikely we will see such feature in JDK (at least in the near future). Other examples like `@Readonly` are also just examples, they are not supposed to be added to JDK.

Please note that using `String.intern()` in the user code is extremely bad. Now it's not so big disaster like it was in JDK6, but it's still bad. You can easily implement your own Object pool using `ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(obj, obj)`.

Comment: It should be noted that the recent Java 8 JVMs have string de-duplication, that is, strings with equal content will get patched to point to the same `char[]` array during garbage collection. So the big redundancy is already handled by the memory management at appropriate times whereas calling `intern()` may save at most the few bytes for the `String` instance only…

Comment: @Holger, IIRC it's still non-default, you should explicitly specify `-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UseStringDeduplication`. Nice addition though.

Comment: G1 String deduplication is also behaviorally different from `String.intern()` in that the former occurs at the backing `char[]` (as Holger mentioned) across _different_ `String` instances that happen to be equivalent, while interning occurs at the `String` object and aims to replace equivalent values with the _same object reference_. The behavioral difference is visible in cases where _reference equality_ is important, e.g. monitors.

Answer (score 1):

This particular annotation seem to originate from [Checker Framework](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#interning-annotations)—an implementation of [pluggable type checking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html) system for Java (which is an amazingly interesting concept by itself). From Checker Framework documentation:

> If the Interning Checker issues no errors for a given program, then all reference equality tests (i.e., all uses of “==”) are proper; that is, == is not misused where equals() should have been used instead.
>
> Interning is a design pattern in which the same object is used whenever two different objects would be considered equal. Interning is also known as canonicalization or hash-consing, and it is related to the flyweight design pattern. Interning has two benefits: it can save memory, and it can speed up testing for equality by permitting use of ==.

and a bit below:

```
@Interned
    indicates a type that includes only interned values (no non-interned values).
```

The Checker Framework is not officially part of Java, but it is developed and promoted by Oracle employees, so it is unsurprising to see this kind of fleeting mentions in Java documentation.

You can read more about the pattern in question in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern#Example_in_Java).

Note, that there are proposals for introducing additional semantics for value-only objects in Java, known under name [Project Valhalla](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/). If those ever get implemented, internability of objects will become a lot more important.